# Modsecurity blocks blocks my legit XHR POST request (403 forbidden)

Tags: nginx, mod-security

I'm new to modsecurity topic so maybe the answer is trivial but...

I have setup modsecurity on my new nginx/1.24.0 server with default set of recommended rules: coreruleset-3.3.0 and since then my POST XHR request is being blocked.
This is a basic Laravel/Livewire form.

The headers sent and logged by modsecurity look like:

```
POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0
content-type: application/json
origin: https://example.com
referer: https://example.com/en
pragma: no-cache
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkJVTXpEK01rYTRYVFI1aGxjOE9T...
content-length: 540
accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
te: trailers
accept: */*
cache-control: no-cache
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-dest: empty
authorization: Basic Y2Z0cmFbjpjmdG9u
host: example.com
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
```

and the logs report:

1. "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric" - but I for me "540" looks numeric!

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^\d+$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-length' (Value: `540' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "127"] 
[id "920160"] 
[msg "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric"] 
[data "540"] 
[severity "2"]
```

2. "Illegal Content-Type header" - how come "application/json" is illegal?

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^[\w/.+-]+(?... against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-type' (Value: `application/json' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "915"] 
[id "920470"] 
[rev ""] 
[msg "Illegal Content-Type header"] 
[data "application/json"] 
[severity "2"]
```

3. "Invalid HTTP Request Line" - what is invalid about this: "POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0"?

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^(?i:(?:[a-... against variable `REQUEST_LINE' (Value: `POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "47"] 
[id "920100"] 
[msg "Invalid HTTP Request Line"] 
[data "POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0"]
```

..and then the request is blocked

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `13' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] 
[line "80"] 
[id "949110"] 
[msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 13)"] 
[data ""] 
[severity "2"]
```

So I'm totally surprised and I don't know what can I do about this since the rules seem legit but also I don't feel like breaking any of them.